# How to display a string up until a certain special character in a textbox from a file

Tags: c#, string, file, textbox

I would want to know how do I display strings from a textfile in a textbox but only untill it reaches a '@" sign in the textfile in c# ?

```
    string lines = outputToBox.ReadToEnd();
//outputToBox is streamreader var that holds the conent of the file
                int index = lines.IndexOf('@');
                txtDisplay.Text = lines.Substring(0, index);
```

The problem I now have is that it does not display all the lines in the textbox only the first one

Comment: Look at `.IndexOf()` and `.Substring()` methods.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You can look into substring, indexOf, and textbox.text

Comment: @kristech Yes I tried working with enumerators and few stuff with linq but I do not understand the concept good enough to use those

Comment: My usual response to these kinds of questions is to write an answer that only uses unsafe code and char*.... please show us what you tried to spare me that :P

Comment: I do use textbox.text... but my problem is more about reading multiple lines from  file and displaying only the parts before the @

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you included an example of what you have and what you want it  to look like. I assume your input looks something like this

```
x.field1@x.field2@x.field3
y.field1@y.field2@y.field3
z.field1@z.field2@z.field3
```

If there are multiple lines in the textbox you could turn it into an array and then run `foreach` through them (if you need an example I can show you)

```
string[] fileInput = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@FILE_PATH)
```

it would output like this

```
fileInput[0] = x.field1@x.field2@x.field3
```

then you can add

```
string[] myArray = fileInput[x].Split('@') // Into an array, so if you only want 'x.field1', you enter fileInput[0], and return myArray[0]
```

and implement your `foreach`. If you want very specific fields from the file that start with certain `chars` I recommend reading a bit about LINQ and how run small queries.

if your goal is to do this for every existing instance of a string in whatever file, you need a loop.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx (LINQ)

Comment: This is the best answer as the question has now come to be written.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick and is probably the optimal solution, without more information >:D.

```
void Main()
{
    Debug.Print(Homework_Problem_Number_54_000_601.
          Parse("NAME SURNAME NUMBER @2131231313"));
    //this prints "NAME SURNAME NUMBER " without the quotes to the console
}

void SetTextBoxText(TextBox textBox, string value) { textBox.Text = value; }

unsafe static class Homework_Problem_Number_54_000_601
{
    [ThreadStatic]static StringBuilder __builder;

    public static string Parse(string textToParse)
    {
        if (textToParse == null) return null;

        var builder = __builder = __builder ?? new StringBuilder();
        builder.clear();

        fixed (char* pTextToParse = textToParse)
        {
            var pTerminus = pTextToParse + textToParse.Length;
            for (var pChar = pTextToParse; pChar < pTerminus; ++pChar)
            {
                switch (*pChar)
                {
                    case '@':
                        return builder.ToString();
                        break;
                    default:
                        builder.Append(*pChar);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("textToParse was not in the expected format");
    }
}
```

As for reading from the file, that's hard to say without a file format specification from you, but now that you have posted code I'd try this:

```
string lines = outputToBox.ReadToEnd();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string line in lines.Split('\n'))
{
   int index = line.IndexOf('@');
   if (index != -1) builder.AppendLine(line.Substring(0, index));
}

txtDisplay.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Don't forget to switch the TextBox to multi-line mode if needed.

Comment: I am using an open file dialog. I seem to have gotten it to work by using the code :    string lines = outputToBox.ReadToEnd();
//outputToBox is streamreader var that holds the conent of the file
                int index = lines.IndexOf('@');
                txtDisplay.Text = lines.Substring(0, index);   
But it only display the first line and not the rest that is in the textfile

Comment: @Quantu-Adunati  I've added the solution at the bottom of my edited answer - please give it a shto.

Comment: It gives an error saying length cannot be less than zero @hoodacticus

Comment: Then not every line in your file has an @ in it.  This is why we need to know more about the file you are trying to parse.  I am editing to add some protection there to ignore lines that have no @ sign in it but you need to understand why that is so.

Comment: I checked and every line in the textfile has a '@' .. Maybe just not at the same index each time

Comment: @Quantu-Adunati - if the first and/or last characters in the file are newline characters then no, not every line contains an '@'.